# sklearn nmf - question about its use

Tags: python, scikit-learn

This is a complete noob question, I'm new to Python, and I understand the basics of NMF, but when implementing it in sklearn it seems a bit convoluted and I wanted to ask whether anyone knows how to exploit the results.

I've imported data from a file, and created and shaped an array, and now have implemented some initial NMF code I took from the sklearn guide online.

```
nmf = NMF(init='nndsvd', max_iter=2000, random_state=0, shuffle=False, solver='cd',verbose=0)
W = nmf.fit_transform(myfile);
H = nmf.components_;

#X_new = np.array(?)
#W_new = model.transform(X_new)
```

But here's the bit I'm getting lost - and why I commented out the last two lines - where does X_new come from, am I meant to be imported another matrix for comparison - I thought the point of NMF was to identify key features of the matrix under analysis?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API allows two types of operations: Learn and transform a matrix under analysis. Or alternatively, learn the factorization on one matrix (myfile / X) and then apply the same transformation on a new matrix (X_new), having the same number of columns (but potentially different number of rows).

Think of it as learning the basis transformation on one set of input data (.fit method) and then apply the same basis transformation on new set of data (.transform method).

If you are interested in transforming the same matrix (myfile in your case), use only the fit_transform method instead of transform.

Comment: Thanks for this, your explanation is great and a lot clearer than the docs. Accepted and voted (though as a noob my non-existent rep means the vote doesn't show publicly :-/ )